# O que é rank-deficient e como contornar isso?

Tags: r, lm

Fiz uma regressão linear `lm()`, onde declarava algumas variáveis como `factor`, e obtive alguns betas como `NA` como:

```
citySão José
NA
```

Quando realizei a predição, ocorreu a predição e recebi o seguinte aviso:

```
Warning message:
In predict.lm(modeloAIC, matriz_de_estimação) :
uma predição a partir de um ajuste rank-deficient pode ser enganoso
```

Me ficou a dúvida de como contornar isso e como foi predito quem tinha o fator São José.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fórmula geral da regressão linear é dada por

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ela pode ser representada de forma matricial através da relação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

em que Y e epsilon são vetores de n elementos e X é uma matriz dada por

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O estimador de mínimos quadrados dos parâmetros beta pode ser obtido através da relação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

em que X' é a transposta de X e (X'X)^(-1) é a inversa de X'X.

Para que a inversa (X'X)^(-1) exista, X'X deve ser uma matriz full rank (ou de posto completo, em português). X'X vai ter posto completo se, e somente se, suas colunas não forem combinações lineares umas das outras. Desta forma, o determinante da matriz é diferente de zero e ela é invertível.

Quando as colunas de uma matriz forem combinações lineares umas das outras, dizemos que a matriz é rank deficient (ou posto incompleto, em português). O problema é que matrizes assim não são invertíveis. Portanto, não dá para estimar os parâmetros da regressão de acordo com a fórmula mostrada anteriormente, pois (X'X)^(-1) não existe.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É impossível dar uma solução para um problema de regressão com matriz *rank-deficient* sem olhar os dados. Entretanto, existem algumas coisas que podem ser tentadas:

1) Uma das variáveis preditoras é combinação linear das demais. Ou seja, alguma variável no teu modelo é redundante. Pesquise sobre multicolinearidade em regressão e como remover variáveis do teu modelo. Veja, principalmente, o que significa variance inflation factor.

Este exemplo abaixo, criado especialmente para ser *rank-deficient*, mostra um comportamento similar ao do teu problema, pois dentre as duas variáveis, uma é exatamente o dobro da outra e, portanto, são uma combinação linear.

```
ajuste <- lm(mpg ~ wt + I(2*wt), data=mtcars)
predict(ajuste, mtcars)

Warning message:
In predict.lm(fit2, mtcars) :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
```

2) Talvez a amostra não seja grande o suficiente para o modelo a ser ajustado. São necessários pelo menos dois pontos para definir uma reta. Entretanto, se eu der um ponto só, com uma coordenada x e outra y, o `R` vai ajustar uma modelo linear a ele, sem reclamar:

```
x <- 1
y <- 3

ajuste <- lm(y ~ x)

predict(ajuste, data.frame(x=1.5))
```

O warning só aparece no momento da predição. Portanto, pode ser que o teu modelo tenha parâmetros demais e tamanho amostral de menos. Veja o caso a seguir, em que há duas variáveis preditoras:

```
x <- c(1, 2)
y <- c(3, 1)
z <- c(5, 0)

ajuste <- lm(z ~ x + y)

predict(ajuste, data.frame(x=1.5, y=2.5))
```

Ele também é *rank-deficient* porque há poucos dados. Veja como o problema é resolvido quando aumento o meu tamanho amostral:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 1)
y <- c(3, 1, 1)
z <- c(5, 0, 1)

ajuste <- lm(z ~ x + y)

predict(ajuste, data.frame(x=1.5, y=2.5))
```

A regra geral é ter *pelo menos* uma quantidade de pontos igual ao número de parâmetros a serem ajustado no modelo. Assim se garante que a matriz não será *rank-deficient*. Mesmo assim não é o ideal, pois outros problemas podem ocorrer. Rode o comando abaixo e veja que não foi possível construir os testes de hipóteses para os parâmetros, mesmo com a matriz não sendo *rank-deficient*.

```
summary(ajuste)
```

E se as variáveis preditoras forem categóricas, há outro agravante, pois a dimensão da matriz (X'X) aumenta de acordo com a quantidade de níveis. A regra que coloquei acima só vale se considerarmos que as variáveis preditoras são quantitativas.

Em resumo:

1. Simplifique o teu modelo; ou
2. Colete mais dados; ou
3. Leia um bom livro de regressão linear múltipla

Comment: Grato, o meu problema estava em algumas categorias de uma das minhas variáveis terem apenas uma amostra. Eu tinha achado interessante R retornar um numero real para uma predição, onde um dos betas era NA, esperava que ele retornasse NA também para aquela predição em particular.

Comment: Ah, então era um problema de tamanho amostral mesmo. Não do tamanho total, mas em algumas determinadas categorias.